# How to make sure to get the Main/External IP without regard to network device type/name

Tags: linux, bash, centos, ip, gentoo

- Hello, I need to make sure I have the external or at least the main **IP** address for a given machine, ***regardless to the device type/name***.
  I quickly wrote that tiny script for that purpose, but I need to know the **drawbacks** of such a script. And whether there is a **better system call** to get for sure the external IP address; if not, the main IP of the host.
  Furthermore, is there any other tool that serves that purpose?
- Subject Machines  are mostly *CentOS 5/6* , *Gentoo 1/2*

> #!/bin/bash

```
#!/bin/bash
#Author: Hanynowsky <hanynowsky@gmail.com>
COM1=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
COM2=$(hostname -i 2>/dev/null)
COM3=$(ip route show 2>/dev/null | grep src | grep -vE 'eth1.*|lo' |  awk -Fsrc '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/ //g')
COM4=$(curl -s monip.org 2>/dev/null | grep -o -E '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+')
COM5=$(host `hostname -f 2>/dev/null` | awk -F[aA]ddress '{print $2}' | sed 's/ //g')
COM6=$(for i in eth0 em1 bond0; do inf=`ip -4 addr show dev $i 2>/dev/null | grep inet -m1 | cut -d/ -f1 | awk '{ print $2}'`;if [[ "$inf" =~ [0-9][0-9]?* ]]; then echo "$inf";fi ;done)
if [[ "$1" =~ local ]] ;then
    COM1=$COM3
fi
if [[ "$1" =~ private ]] ;then
    COM1=$COM2
fi
if [[ "$1" =~ host ]] ;then
    COM1=$COM5
fi
IP=''
validip()
{
    local  ip=$1
    local  stat=1     
    if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]; then
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS='.'
        ip=($ip)
        IFS=$OIFS
        [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
        stat=$?
    fi  
    if [ "$stat" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo $IP
    else
        echo $stat
    fi  
    return $stat
}
if [ -n "${COM1}" ];then
    IP=${COM1}
    eval validip $IP
    exit
fi

if [ -n "${COM2}" ];then
    IP=${COM2}
    eval validip $IP
    exit
fi
if [ -n "${COM3}" ];then
    IP=${COM3}
    eval validip $IP
    exit
fi
if [ -n "${COM4}" ];then
    IP=${COM4}
    eval validip $IP
    exit
fi

if [ -n "${COM5}" ];then
    IP=${COM5}
    eval validip $IP
    exit
fi
if [ -n "${COM6}" ];then
    IP=${COM6}
    eval validip $IP
    exit
fi
exit
```